# String in the .ts file from an external JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm a little lost on this subject. 
Is it possible to put a string in the .ts file from an external JSON?
I want to show in an IONIC InAppBrowser the urls of each JSON item. And that's why I want to create a variable with a specific item, so I can put it in the InAppBrowser.

Thank you for your attention

**Items.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

//Importando servicio
import { ItemsProvider } from '../../providers/items/items';
//Importando URL desde config
import { URL_SERVICIOS } from './../../config/url.servicios';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-items-eur',
  templateUrl: 'items-eur.html',
})
export class ItemsEurPage {

  pais = {};

  imagenes = URL_SERVICIOS + "/imgs";
  itemsData:any [] = [];
  sliderValue: number = 0;
  sel: string = "";
  itemAsn: string = "";

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public _creP: ItemsProvider,
  ) {
    console.log( navParams );
    this.pais = this.navParams.get("pais");

    if (this.pais == "España") {
      this._creP.cargar_items_esp()
        .subscribe(
          (respuesta)=>{
          console.log(respuesta);
          this.itemsData = respuesta["resultados"];
      } )
    }

    this.itemAsn = this.itemsData[0],["acf"],["enlace"]; //This string I want to show for each item


    console.log(this.itemAsn);

  }
}
```

**JSON FILE**

```js
{
    "resultados": [{
            "acf": {
                "name": "Item1",
                "enlace": "https://www.google.com"
            }
        },
         "acf": {
                "name": "Item2",
                "enlace": "https://www.facebook.com"
          
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE - Load JSON file of ItemsProvider**

```js
  cargar_items_esp(){
    return this.http.get("https://mi_server.com/items_esp.json");
  }
```

Comment: JSON file is on remote url or in local file directory? where it is located?

Comment: JSON is on remote url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your JSON object and `console.log()` all the items in one line. Here is the link to the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w4rpzs

```
var json = {
    "resultados": [
        {
            "acf": {
                "name": "Item1",
                "enlace": "https://www.google.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "acf": {
                "name": "Item2",
                "enlace": "https://www.facebook.com"

            }
        }
    ]
};

json.resultados.forEach(
  (res) => {
    console.log('Name: ' + res.acf.name + ' Enlace: ' + res.acf.enlace);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. The JSON file is on a remote server, not a local file, how can I navigate through it?